# logstash - remove all non digit characters from field

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have log files that I am passing into logstash to be modified before pushing to elasticsearch.

One of the fields that I have sometimes appears as a series of digits

```
foobar = 42
```

Sometimes it is prefixed with letters

```
foobar = ws-42
```

I want to make sure the field is always an integer, and if any non-digits are present, that they are removed.

Here is part of the logstash config which makes sure the field is an integer

```
filter {
  mutate {
    convert => [ "foobar", "integer"]
  }
}
```

How can I strip out the characters if present?

**Update**

By using the mutate filter I can either strip out non numerical values, or I can convert to integers. However if I try and do both, it returns 0.

Example

```
input {
  stdin {}
}

filter {
  kv { }
  mutate {
    gsub => [ "foobar", "\D", "" ]
    convert => [ "foobar", "integer" ]
  }
}
```

Here is the output. Notice that if '42' is provided, then foobar returns an integer of 42, however if you provide 'sw-42' foobar returns 0

```
foobar="42"
{
       "message" => "foobar=\"42\"",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-03-31T22:32:11.718Z",
          "host" => "swat-logstash02",
        "foobar" => 42
}
foobar="sw-42"
{
       "message" => "foobar=\"sw-42\"",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-03-31T22:32:23.822Z",
          "host" => "swat-logstash02",
        "foobar" => 0
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a scoping issue.

If you do just the gsub (without the convert), it shows that the regexp is working:

```
{
       "message" => "foobar=\"sw-42\"",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-03-31T22:42:40.097Z",
          "host" => "0.0.0.0",
        "foobar" => "42"
}
```

so you should run it as two stanzas:

```
filter {
  kv { }
  mutate {
    gsub => [ "foobar", "\D", "" ]
  }
  mutate {
    convert => [ "foobar", "integer" ]
  }
}
```